# Datetime.ParseExact() is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have compiled the below code in c#

```
string datetime = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", root.SelectSingleNode("lasttime").InnerText);



lastUpdateTimestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(datetime, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

but in output i am getting lastUpdateTimestamp is 2/8/2013 7:00:24 AM instead of 02/08/2013 07:00:24 AM

Any idea what i am missing?

After getting this value i am running a query and getting this error

```
Invalid month in timestamp "2": cannot find leading zero [SQL query syntax invalid or unsupported.]
```

Hi All , i got the solution , Rather than passing lastUpdateTimestamp i am now taking date in a string variable and teking its value in proper format. Its working

Comment: What is the value of root.SelectSingleNode("lasttime").InnerText ?

Comment: How are they different ? you are looking at a `DateTime` object which as such doesn't have any specific format to display

Comment: @ animaonline 02/08/2013 07:00:24 AM

Comment: You are asking for `DateTime.ParseExact` but you are complaining about the string formatting. What is the problem now? You haven't shown the code where you format the `DateTime`.

Comment: I am getting output as lastUpdateTimestamp.ToString(). It should be 02/08/2013 07:00:24 AM but it is showing 2/8/2013 7:00:24 AM

Comment: @Aquarius24: You get an exception from your database? You should really use parameters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`root.SelectSingleNode("lasttime").InnerText` returns a string.

You are trying to use a DateTime format specifier to format a string.

Not sure what you are trying to do but something like this should work

```
string xmlstring = root.SelectSingleNode("lasttime").InnerText;
DateTime parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(xmlstring, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt");

string datetime = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", parsed);
```

Comment: Updated the parseexact format to allow single digit month,day and hour

Answer (score 0):

From comment:

> I am getting output as lastUpdateTimestamp.ToString(). It should be 02/08/2013 07:00:24 AM but it is showing 2/8/2013 7:00:24 AM

`lastUpdateTimestamp.ToString()` will format using the general datetime format for the current culture.  In your case, this is obviously `M/dd/yyyy...`.

If you want a different format, you need to specify it as a parameter to `DateTime.ToString`, e.g.:

```
lastUpdateTimestamp.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

or for a fixed format independent of the current culture:

```
lastUpdateTimestamp.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 0):

So your question is not how to parse a string to a `DateTime` with `Datetime.ParseExact` but how to get the correct string from a `DateTime`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string dtStr = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"
                          , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Result:

```
08/02/2013 10:20:18 AM
```

But since you're getting an exception from your database:

> cannot find leading zero [SQL query syntax invalid or unsupported

You should really use parameters and pass the `DateTime` instead of a `string`!